# AngularjS $injector:unpr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a following controllers:

```
/** Calculation controller **/
app.controller('calculationController', ['$scope','$modal','content', function($scope, $modal, content) {

    /** data recieved from get request **/
    $scope.data = content.data; //promise

    /** function to edit data **/
    $scope.edit = function(item){

        var htmlContents = {
            title: 'Edit product',
            body: 'Please confirm that you want to edit the product'
        }

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : templateBase + 'views/modal/dialog.html',
            controller : 'modalInstanceController',
            resolve : {
                items : function() { return item; },
                html : function() { return htmlContents; }
            }
        });
    }

    /** function to delete data **/
    $scope.trash = function(item){

    }
}]);

app.controller('modalInstanceController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance','items','html', function($scope,$modalInstance,items,html) {
    $scope.title = html.title;
    $scope.body  = html.body;
}]);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to open a dialog with contents from 'dialog.html' however once I click the :

```
<img ng-src="images/icn_edit.png" ng-click="edit(item)" alt="Edit">
```

$injector:unpr is appearing in console log.

dialog.html contents are :

```
<div ng-controller="modalInstanceController">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{body}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I know that I'm missing to inject something however after hours of looking at the code I'm unable to locate what...

From what I can observe '$scope', '$modalInstance','items','html' are being injected in modelInstanceController..

Any help appreciated.

thank you

Comment: You are not using $http dependency in your controller. Remove that and check if your error persists. If it does not work share your modal dialog html template

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tested but issue still appears.
- amended the example

Comment: @Gor81 can you share your modal instance template ie dialog.html

Comment: @gor181 is 'item' undefined? i dont see it anywhere in your code - assignment to item

Comment: @HarishR - item is an object provided through view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your dialog.html remove

```
Ng-controller="modalInstanceController"
```

It should be plain div and that will do the trick

Your html markup for dialog.html should look like this:

```
<div>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{body}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome if it answered please upvote and accept as an answer